# extract file using bash in one tar file but composed of many tar files inside

Tags: linux, bash, loops, tar

I have created a script below and when I execute it, I face a problem. Instead to extract it 5 times it will just extract once. So how to get this issue resolved?

```
i=0

   for tarfile in *.tar.gz;
                        do
                        ((i++))
                         [ $i = 5 ] && break ;
                tar -xzvf $tarfile
                done
                rm -rvf $tarfile
```

Help is greatly appreciated. I want to extract the `tar.gz` file and inside of it is only tar.gz file. Noted: it is decompressed 5 times and I want to get the last `tar.gz` file decompressed. Please help me.

Comment: You have 5 layers of compression or five distinct tarballs?

Comment: I have 5 layers of compression. For ex: file.tar.gz inside of it is also tar.gz and so-on ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If and only if** the filenames for each of the nested tar do not collide, you can do the following.

```
for i in `seq 1 4`; do name=$(ls *.tar.gz); tar xvfz $name; rm $name; done;
```

If they are *all* the same, like `foo.tar.gz` inside `foo.tar.gz` inside `foo.tar.gz`, you can simply delete the `rm $name` from the above.

If there are only *some* collisions you will have to play more clever tricks, such as moving intermediate files into another directory.

**Update**: If you just want to move the final tar to a new directory, just do use `mv` after the loop above.

```
mv *.tar.gz OtherDirectoryName
```

Comment: I got problem for the script you have given. It will extract all tar.gz. My point here is just to extract the first 4 and the last one will remain the same

Comment: @user3626800, Then change the `5` to a `4`.

Comment: thank you, another question .. how to move the last `tar.gz` file to other directory ? can you add it to your given script ?

Comment: @user3626800, See the update. If you are going to be doing shell scripting a lot, you should get a [good tutorial](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/CoursePage.php?course=PracticalUnix) on the basics.

Comment: ,after moving the *.tar.gz to other directory I want to extract it there specifically to that directory and again there is another `tar.gz` file that schould not be extracted